# Orbeon - strange behaviour - radio-buttons

Tags: radio-button, orbeon

I got a strange issue with Orbeon Forms. It might be a problem with styles, but I'm not sure. When I put validation on radio-type control, I got an asterisk icon, what is normal. These asterisks show up signed to every answer.

[image: click1]
[image: click2]

Comment: Yes, this is most likely due to some custom CSS you have on your side. Are you using Form Builder? Would you be able to disable any custom CSS you have, to check if that is the problem?

Comment: Just checking: were you able to figure this out, after disabling your own custom CSS?

Comment: Hey,
Yes, I use Form Builder. Actually im not sure, how im suposed to turn off the styles.

I just added 2 lines to get form wider because of its construction:

 <xh:style type="text/css">
     
   .orbeon .fr-mode-new .navbar {width: 1366px; margin: 0 auto;}            
   .orbeon .fr-mode-new .row {width: 1366px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 75px; background-color: #fff;}
   </xh:style>

Im not an administrator of this environment and i think there are styles attached much deeper, out of my view.

@avernet

Comment: Got it, so I'd recommend you get in touch with the person or group who put in place those styles, tell them about the problem they are causing to radio buttons, and they should be able to fix the CSS to avoid this problem.

Comment: @avernet

Hey, somehow I have fixed it. Now validation sign isnt visible at all. Temporarly it helps me right now.

Comment: Got it, and I'm glad you made progress on this, and hopefully you can iron out the remaining wrinkles in the CSS.